# c# combobox заполнять по принципу MVP

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

пытаюсь написать приложение по паттерну MVP. пытаюсь понять, для заполнения контроллеров из разных таблиц базы данных нужно создать несколько моделей, объясните пожалуйста. допустим для одной формы для отображения данных в Datagridview создал один модель, в этой же форме нужно заполнять combobox данными из бд. почему-то не получается, объясните пожалуйста где ошибка моя. ниже выложил код. заранее извиняюсь, выложил весь код, чтоб понят где, что.

```
      public class ProductModel
{
    // поля
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private int qty;
    private int price;
    private int categoryID;
    private int companyID;
    private DateTime date;
    private string categoryValueName;

    // свойство поля (properties) 
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public int Qty
    {
        get { return qty; }
        set { qty = value; }
    }
    public int Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }
    public int Category
    {
        get { return categoryID; }
        set { categoryID = value; }
    } 
    public int Company
    {
        get {return companyID; }
        set { companyID = value; }
    }
      [DisplayName ("Date")]
     public DateTime Date
      {
          get { return date; }
          set { date = value; }
      } 
    
}
```

**новая модель для combobox**

```
    public partial class CategoryModel
{
    private int CategoryID;
    private string CategoryName;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return CategoryID; }
        set { CategoryID = value; }
    } 
    public string Name
    {
        get { return CategoryName; }
        set { CategoryName = value; }
    }

}
```

---

```
      public class ProductRepository : BaseRepository, IProductRepository
{
    // конструкторы
    public ProductRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;}
    // Методы
    public void Add(ProductModel productModel)
    {}
    public void Delete(int id)
    {}
    public void Edit(ProductModel productModel)
    {}
    public IEnumerable<ProductModel> GetAll()
    {
        var productList = new List<ProductModel>();
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * from sklad order by id desc";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var productModel = new ProductModel();
                    productModel.Id = (int)reader[0];
                    productModel.Name = reader[1].ToString();
                    productModel.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]);
                    productModel.Price = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
                    productModel.Category = Convert.ToInt32(reader[4]);
                    productModel.Company = Convert.ToInt32(reader[5]);
                    productModel.Date = (DateTime)reader[6];
                    productList.Add(productModel);
                }

            }
        }
        return productList;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> GetCategoryModel()   // запрос в базу для комбобокс
    {
        var categoryList = new List<CategoryModel>();
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT category.id AS id, CONCAT(category.id, '|', category.name) as name FROM category";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
                    categoryModel.Id = (int)reader[0];
                    categoryModel.Name = reader[1].ToString();
                    categoryList.Add(categoryModel);
                }

            }
        }
        return categoryList;
    }
```

---

```
       public interface IProductRepository
{
    void Add(ProductModel productModel);
    void Edit(ProductModel productModel);
    void Delete(int id);
    IEnumerable<ProductModel> GetAll();  // Интерфейс IEnumerable реализует перебор объектов (продуктов)
    IEnumerable<ProductModel> GetValueForSearch(string value);   // Интерфейс долже реализовать поиск товара 
    IEnumerable<CategoryModel> GetCategoryModel();
}
```

**интерфейс view**

```
     public interface IProductView
{
    // свойство поля (properties - fields)

   string ProductId { get; set; }
   string ProducttName { get; set; }
   string ProductQty { get; set; }
   string ProductPrice { get; set; }
   string ProductCategory { get; set; }
   string ProductCompany { get; set; }
    string ProductDate { get; set; }
   string SearchValue { get; set; }
    string CategoryID { get; set; }
    string CategoryName { get; set; }

    // Events (методы обработчик событий при нажатие на кнопки)
    event EventHandler SearchEvent;
    event EventHandler AddNewEvent;
    event EventHandler EditEvent;
    event EventHandler DeleteEvent;
    event EventHandler SaveEvent;
    event EventHandler CancelEvent;

    // Методы
    void SetProductListBindingSource(BindingSource productList);  // инкапцилурет источника данных для формы
 
    void SetCategoryListBindingSource(BindingSource categoryList);
```

**и форма**

```
public partial class ProductView : Form, IProductView
{
    // Конструктор
    public ProductView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AssociateAndRaiseViewEvents();
        //  tabControlAdd.TabPages.Remove(tabPageAdd);
    }

    private void AssociateAndRaiseViewEvents() // вызов событий или еще что-то
    {
        //событие Поиска
        btnSearch.Click += delegate { SearchEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); };
        SearchTextbox.KeyDown += (s, e) => {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                SearchEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);};
    }

    // свойство
    public string ProductId
    {
        get { return IdTextbox.Text; }
        set { IdTextbox.Text = value; }
    }
    public string ProductQty
    {
        get { return QtyTextbox.Text; }
        set { QtyTextbox.Text = value; }
    }
    public string ProductPrice
    {
        get { return PriceTextbox.Text; }
        set { PriceTextbox.Text = value; }
    }
       public string ProductCategory
    {
        get { return comboBoxCategoryName.Text; }
        set { comboBoxCategoryName.Text = value; }
    } 

    public string ProductCompany
    {
        get { return comboBoxCompanyName.Text; }
        set { comboBoxCompanyName.Text = value; }
    }
    public string ProductDate
    {
        get { return dateTimePicker1.Text; }
        set { dateTimePicker1.Text = value; }

    }
    public string ProducttName 
    {
        get { return NameTextbox.Text; }
        set { NameTextbox.Text = value; }
    }
    public string SearchValue
    {
        get { return SearchTextbox.Text; }
        set { SearchTextbox.Text = value; }

    }

    public string CategoryID
    {
        get {return comboBoxCategoryName.ValueMember; }
        set { comboBoxCategoryName.ValueMember = value; }
    }
    public string CategoryName
    {
        get { return comboBoxCategoryName.DisplayMember; }
        set { comboBoxCategoryName.DisplayMember = value; }
    }

    // Events - события
    public event EventHandler SearchEvent;
    public event EventHandler AddNewEvent;
    public event EventHandler EditEvent;
    public event EventHandler DeleteEvent;
    public event EventHandler SaveEvent;
    public event EventHandler CancelEvent;

    // Методы
    public void SetProductListBindingSource(BindingSource productList)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = productList;
    }
    public void SetCategoryListBindingSource(BindingSource categoryList)
    {
        comboBoxCategoryName.DataSource = categoryList;
    }
}
```

Comment: MVP это конечно отлично, но если вы уже до этого дошли, не проще ли взять WPF и MVVM? Там оно все намного проще делается. Я просто не так давно вспотел верстать нормальный интерфейс в винформах, тогда как в WPF такое по умолчанию работает.

Comment: @aepot,  очень хочется использовать WPF, но пока нормально не разобравшись в MVP перейти в WPF кажется сложно будет для меня

Comment: @aepot, нужно  заполнять несколько combobox-ов в одной форме, самой форме как получить IEnumerable, тут не понятно

Comment: MVP и MVVM сильно отличаются, при чем второй - проще. XAML конечно под WPF придется изучить.

Comment: @я с удовольствием, но перешагнут через базу тоже не хочу, реализовать конкретный проект это хоть что-то, хотя конкретные примеры по MVP очень мало встречал в интернете